# Why do the values of the array change after reading a line?

Tags: java, arrays, file

```
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
 String line;
 int[] data = null;

 while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] a = line.split(","); //read in all numbers in file
    data = new int[a.length]; //convert those numbers from Strings to ints
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        data[i] = Integer.parseInt(a[i]);
        System.out.print(data[i] + ","); //testing
    }
 }

 System.out.println();
 for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        System.out.print(data[i] + ",");
 }
```

A file just consists of 1 line of numbers separated by commas, such as:

```
5,4,
1,-1,-1,1,1,
1,0,3,4,1,
1,0,2,2,1,
1,1,1,1,1,
```

The program crates a string array containing only the numbers, and then creates an integer array in the same order. But changing the strings to ints instead, then to verify that the int array contains the values in the file, prints out the int array.

This code outputs:

```
5,4,1,-1,-1,1,1,1,0,3,4,1,1,0,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,
1,1,1,1,1,
```

As you can see the first line of numbers, which corresponds to the print functions inside the while block, prints correctly. But when the array is iterated and printed again outside the while block, suddenly it is completely different, why is this the case? The array should be the same outside the while block.

Comment: Please can you confirm the contents of your file. It looks to me as if you have a line break with `1,1,1,1,1` on a separate line. This will cause a problem as `data` is reinitialized with each line read.

Comment: 5,4,
1,-1,-1,1,1,
1,0,3,4,1,
1,0,2,2,1,
1,1,1,1,1,

Comment: if the contents were exactly what you have just posted you'll get a `NumberFormatException`. I have tried your code and it works fine with a correctly formatted text file (single line, no extra white space).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to edit your question, I saw that you pasted:

```
5,4,
1,-1,-1,1,1,
1,0,3,4,1,
1,0,2,2,1,
1,1,1,1,1,
```

So, I can imagine that your file is in this way.

If you execute this code:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Path_to/java.txt"));
        String line;
        int[] data = null;

        while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] a = line.split(","); //read in all numbers in file
            data = new int[a.length]; //convert those numbers from Strings to ints
            System.out.println("1data.length: " + data.length);
            for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                data[i] = Integer.parseInt(a[i]);
                System.out.println(data[i] + ","); //testing
            }
        }

        System.out.println("data.length: " + data.length);
        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

            System.out.print(data[i] + ",");
        }

    }
```

You could see that **data.length** is 5 at the end (for obvious reason). That's why in

```
 for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        System.out.print(data[i] + ",");
 }
```

You see

```
1,1,1,1,1,
```

Comment: Yes, I think I understand it now, on notepad it looks like 1 line of of text, but apparently there are multiple lines (you can sort of see an extra space on stackoverflow, denoting the new line?)

Comment: @ApprentlyOk Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted: stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

After testing your code I found it to work fine with a correctly formatted text file. Correctly formatted being a single line, comma separated integers with no extra white spacing.

Example valid text file for your program:

```
5,4,1,-1,-1,1,1,1,0,3,4,1,1,0,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1
```

If you have line breaks in your file, the the array `data` will be reinitialized with a new array equal to the length of the current split line. As a result, `data` will contain only the last line read.

I'd propose as a better solution the use of a `List`, since the number of integers may be unknown, and `Scanner` to read the text file using a delimiter ",". Additionally, whilst 'scanning' the text file, remove all the extra white space preventing a `NumberFormatException` occurring when using `Integer.valueOf()` should any white space exist. This approach will enable less well formed text files to be read. Note, this will still cause an exception if the file does not contain only integers.

For example:

```
String fileName = "test.txt";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
scanner.useDelimiter(",");
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    // add the parsed integer to the list, removing split space.
    result.add(Integer.valueOf(scanner.next().replaceAll("\\s+", "")));
}

// Display contents
String output = "";
for (int value : result) {
    if (!output.isEmpty()) {
        output += ", ";
    }
    output += value;
}
System.out.println(output);
```